# How to save user data (server side) when user is Not logged in, then move data to his account?

Tags: laravel, session

I need to save some user data on server - when use is not logged in and then when the user logs in, I need to move that data to his new session.
It is like a shopping cart but with more data and needs to be saved server side.

Any idea how to do this in Laravel pls?

The login is just the default one from Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: could you please share the login function

Comment: @omaresmaeel is just the std Laravel login. I could implement this manually - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this in the login function

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $data = $request->session()->all(); //get the data of the guest session
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        $request->session()->put($data); // add it to the new auth session 
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: It is a bit more complicated as data saved in db will be keyed by oldsession (I think) and also the image saved on server could be on old session folder (?) so I could map them somehow. I was wondering if there is a recommended way to do this other than me doing stuff. This also looks like a security risk.